# How to Auto route Outputs for vocals in Ableton with a Midi Dummy?

Tags: midi, ableton-live, live

here's my problem.

My band plays in bars every night and we have created Backing Tracks for all 300 Songs, some of them with Percusion Audio & Fx's... but 70% are just a Cue intro + the metronome.

We have 3 vocalist, and they sing lead in different songs.

We have a TC Helicon Voicelive Touch 1, and i want to know if there's a way to auto route the Lead Singer channel to the TCH.

Singer 1 : In 1 - Out 1 (Console)
Singer 2 : In 2 - Out 2 (Console)
Singer 3 : In 3 - Out 3 (Console)

We wish to use the TC helicon as an AUX for FX only.  Longs Rvbs or Delays etc etc or we can also use it as an Input & Output 4.

But we want to be able to route the lead vocalist trough the Out 4 but also be able to do it automatically instead of Assigning Keys on the laptop.  That way we can build a MIDI track that goes with the Backing Tracks and Auto Change the TC Helicon Preset.

A lot of work but in the end it will be worth it.

Building the MIDI track to change the TC Helicon preset is easy, but we can't figure out how to assign  any MIDI or i don't know what to the Backing track to auto Route the vocalist who sings the specific song through the TC helicon.

That way we can use 1 TC Helicon for the 3 vocalist instead using 1 TC helicon for each vocalist.

HELP PLEASE!

Comment: So is there a separate Ableton Live project file for each song? Then go through each and save it with the proper routing for that song's lead vocalist? Or are the backing tracks as MIDI files somewere? Then you'd want to control Ableton's routing/mixing settings with MIDI CC commands or something.

Comment: Yes, we created a separate ableton project for each song, but we have a Master Project so we add in the master launch every song we want to play, and just click the song to begin, is easier that way instead of needing to open each song project.  we import the stems into a Audio track, an Midi track with the Cues for the songs, and we control all of them with the master launch... the thing is trying to fin a way where we can  launch a Midi CC that triggers the routing for each vocal microphone instead of doing that with Key commands.

Comment: You could use Sends to send into the output connected to the TC Helicon, and then record automation of the send knobs into clips in the vocal tracks, with Monitoring set to In, so the clips only control automation and don't output actual audio. Or you could set up MIDI Remote control for the sends, and send control events to a virtual or hardware MIDI loopback from a MIDI track, with the MIDI input set to Remote On. IOW, send control events to MIDI Out X connected to MIDI In Y, and MIDI In Y set to Remote On. And do NOT enable/route that MIDI input in such a way that you'd cause MIDI feedback.